# JSP sample choice quiz

Tags: jsp, server-side

I am trying to create a multiple choice html page and need to use jsp to view the results.  However, I can't seem to figure out how to get a jsp file to get the final score results after hitting the submit button. (for example, you got _ out of 4 questions correct _%)  I can set up the html file just fine.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

below is an example page with the html code "SampleQuiz.html"

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Multiple-Choice Quiz Example</title>
</head>

<h2>Sample Multiple-Choice Quiz</h2>

<form action="quizresults.jsp" method="get">

<h3>Q1. What color is the sky on a sunny day?</h3>
<input type="radio" name="answer1" value="blue" checked="checked">blue<br>
<input type="radio" name="answer1" value="red">red<br>
<input type="radio" name="answer1" value="green">green<br>

<h3>Q2. The sum of two and three equals...</h3>
<input type="radio" name="answer2" value="seven">seven<br>
<input type="radio" name="answer2" value="six">six<br>
<input type="radio" name="answer2" value="five" checked="checked" >five<br>

<h3>Q3. Which of these animals is NOT an mammal.</h3>
<input type="radio" name="answer3" value="lizard" checked="checked">lizard<br>
<input type="radio" name="answer3" value="monkey">monkey<br>
<input type="radio" name="answer3" value="dog">dog<br>

<h3>Q4. Santa Claus is most associated with this holiday.</h3>
<input type="radio" name="answer4" value="Halloween">Halloween<br>
<input type="radio" name="answer4" value="Christmas"checked="checked">Christmas<br>
<input type="radio" name="answer4" value="Fourth of July">Forth of July<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Update:  here's my second attempt at jsp.  I also changed the html to the below answer's suggestion.

below is my attempted jsp code "quizresults.jsp"

```
<html>

  <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

        <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Final Quiz Score</title>
   </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Here are your results</h1>

       <%
               if(request.getParameter("answer") != null) {
                   if(request.getParameter("answer").equals("answer1")) {
                       out.println("Question 1 was correct<br>");
                }
                else {
                    out.println("Question 1 was incorrect.  Try again.<br>");
                }
                if(request.getParameter("answer").equals("answer2")) {
                    out.println("Question 2 was answered.<br>");
                }
                else {
                    out.println("Question 2 was incorrect.  Try again.<br>");
                }
                if(request.getParameter("answer").equals("answer3")) {
                    out.println("Question 3 was answered.<br>");
                }
                else {
                    out.println("Question 3 was incorrect.  Try again.<br>");
                }
                if(request.getParameter("answer").equals("answer4")) {
                    out.println("Question 4 was correct.<br>");
                }
                else {
                    out.println("Question 4 was incorrect.  Try again.<br>");
                }
            }
    %>

     <form action="SampleQuiz.html" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Return">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

for checking answers right or not u must replace

```
            if(request.getParameter("answer").equals("answer1")) {
                   out.println("Question 1 was correct<br>");
```

with this

```
           if(request.getParameter("answer1").equals("blue")) {
                   out.println("Question 1 was correct<br>");
```

and also i am not seening any answer parameter passed by you from html which you are using for null check in jsp like this

```
      if(request.getParameter("answer") != null)
```

i think you don't have to  use this null check because you have checked one radio button in each question by default so it will always pass your checked  values.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to understand how forms and radio buttons work.

First of all, what is sent as parameter are the name/value pairs: the names are `<input>` names, and the values are `<input>` values. In the case of radio buttons, only the checked radios name and value are submitted.

Since all your radios have the same name, only one of them can be checked at once, and the for will thus submit only one parameter: `answer=<the value of the unique checked radio button>`.

Your server-side code, which really should be in a servlet and not in scriptlets, doesn't make sense: you're checking the value of a parameter named "questions". But no input has this name, so the value of this parameter will always be null.

What you need is to give each set of radio buttons a distinct name:

```
<h3>Q1. What color is the sky on a sunny day?</h3>
<input type="radio" name="answer1" value="blue" checked="checked">blue<br>
<input type="radio" name="answer1" value="red">red<br>
<input type="radio" name="ansser1" value="green">green<br>

<h3>Q2. The sum of two and three equals...</h3>
<input type="radio" name="answer2" value="seven">seven<br>
<input type="radio" name="answer2" value="six">six<br>
<input type="radio" name="answer2" value="five" checked="checked" >five<br>
```

Then, at server-side, you can get the checked answer of the first question using

```
request.getParameter("answer1"); // null if nothing checked, blue, red or green otherwise
```

And, similarly, to get the checked answer of the second question:

```
request.getParameter("answer2"); // null if nothing checked, seven, six or five otherwise
```

Comment: Thanks.  I thought that I only had to change just the value and not the name.  Also, so i change the getParameter from "questions" to answers" on the jsp, correct?

Comment: No, not correct. Read my answer. It tells you what to do.